# при нажатии на чекбокс не скрывается колонока в таблице

Tags: reactjs

Не срабатывает событие чекбокса 
Пример тут https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-zjgr2

```
    class TablePagin extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          posts: [],
          firstColumnSelected: true
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({ posts: data });
          });
      }

      handleInputChange(value) {
        this.setState({ firstColumnSelected: !this.state.firstColumnSelected });
      }

      render() {
        const { data, firstColumnSelected } = this.state.posts;
        const columns = [
          {
            columns: [
              {
                Header: "Post ID",
                accessor: "postId",
                show: firstColumnSelected
              },
              {
                Header: "ID",
                accessor: "id"
              },
              {
                Header: "Name",
                accessor: "name"
              },
              {
                Header: "Email",
                accessor: "email"
              },
              {
                Header: "Body",
                accessor: "body"
              }
            ]
          }
        ];
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <input
                name="firstColumn"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.state.firstColumnSelected}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
              />
              <label>Скрыть первую колонку</label>
            </div>
            <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.posts} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default TablePagin;
```

Comment: Если вдруг запутаетесь как фильтровать первую колонку - 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-8yyd7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { data, firstColumnSelected } = this.state.posts;
```

Исправьте на

```
const { data, firstColumnSelected } = this.state;
```